# NextPageNumber in footer in MS excel and word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

We can add [Page] and also  [Pages] in excel in header or footer.

But I want to add  [Page] in the header and then "continue on [NextPageNumber]" in footer.

[NextPageNumber] do not exist in excel/ word; is there any work around?

Comment: a quick internet search yields https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-numbers-to-page-number-using-a-formula/a1e31e79-43ce-4ed7-a39a-2864a05b0ec8

Answer (score 0):

If what you refer to as "`[NextPageNumber]`" is not on the directly following page,
you might be successful using a cross-reference **in Word**.

As you bring up the dialog for insertion on a cross-reference you will see bulleted and numbered lists, bookmarks and other similar positions listed.
Just choose the relevant one and then tell in which style to insert it;
e.g. as a page number or with the text itself.
*(have not tried this in Excel /header/footer/, but would expect it to work in a similar manner)*.

Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-cross-reference-300b208c-e45a-487a-880b-a02767d9774b

Comment: I do not think this would work in Word. Headers and footers are not really on a page but are in a Section. It works in the body of the document.

Comment: Maybe footnotes is an option here? At least in word; not sure Excel has them...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Excel.

### In Word you would use a calculation field.

Continued on page `{ = { PAGE } + 1 }` in your footer

Obviously, you do not want this on the last page, though.
See my solution [for footer for last page only](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#last_page).

```
{ IF { PAGE } = { NUMPAGES } "This is the last page" "Continued on page { = { PAGE } + 1 }" }
```

That is an [IF Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#IF_field) that checks whether or not you are on the last page. If you have formatted your page numbers to restart, it will have to be fiddled with.